# ReportViewer Multiple Report Parameters

Tags: vb.net, parameters, reportviewer

Is it possible to include multiple report parameters in a single line? if i have like 10 parameters, i don't want to create an "add" keyword 10 times ...

```
LocalReport.SetParameters("NewParameter1", "First one")
```

Having to repeat that would seem redundant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store the parameters in an **array** ... For example:

```
Dim rpTitle = New ReportParameter("rpTitle", "Your title")
Dim rpDate = New ReportParameter("rpDate", Date.Now())
Dim HeaderParams As ReportParameter() = {rpTitle, rpDate}
```

Now you have an array which contains two report parameters ... (it can include much more).

Then you just need to loop through the HeaderParams array like so:

```
For Each param As ReportParameter In HeaderParams
    LocalReport.SetParameters(param)
Next
```

That way you don't need to SetParameters more than once in your code... The loop will do it.

Comment: I think you could use **LocalReport.SetParameters(HeaderParams)** directly and not use the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim param As ReportParameter() = New ReportParameter(2) {}

    For i As Int16 = 0 To 2
        param(i) = New ReportParameter("item" & i + 1, tb_PartDesc.Text)
    Next

    viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(param)
```

add item1 item2 item3 in reportviewer parameter
[image]